# Nullable object must have a value in IComparable.CompareTo

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a custom class that needs to be sortable using a Nullable(of Double) property.  I have defined the class, and implemented iCompare.  Within my code, I *thought* I had placed sufficient checks for Null values, but I am suddenly seeing this error...

> Nullable object must have a value.

...on this line:

```
Return Me.SomeDouble.Value.CompareTo(CType(obj, MatrixCellData).SomeDouble.Value)
```

Can anyone please explain why this is happening?  I know that usually this error can be easily avoided by using `Double.HasValue`, which I have included. The full sample code to reproduce is below.

```
Namespace MyApp

    Public Class MatrixCellData
        Implements IComparable

        Public Property SomeDouble As Nullable(Of Double)

        Public Function CompareTo(obj As Object) As Integer Implements System.IComparable.CompareTo
            If obj Is Nothing OrElse IsDBNull(obj) OrElse Not TypeOf (obj) Is MatrixCellData Then
                Return 1
            Else
                If Not Me.SomeDouble.HasValue Then
                    Return -1
                Else
                    Return Me.SomeDouble.Value.CompareTo(CType(obj, MatrixCellData).SomeDouble.Value)
                End If
            End If
        End Function

    End Class

End Namespace
```

Breaking code...

```
Dim lst As New List(Of MyApp.MatrixCellData)
lst.Add(New MyApp.MatrixCellData With {.SomeDouble = 75})
lst.Add(New MyApp.MatrixCellData With {.SomeDouble = 25})
lst.Add(New MyApp.MatrixCellData With {.SomeDouble = Nothing})
lst.Sort() ' Triggers error
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't use

```
If Not Me.SomeDouble.HasValue Then
```

Then there's no check to stop Me.SomeDouble from being equal to Nothing.

When you call the sort function on your list, you will be calling the CompareTo function at least once for each item. Effectively, the framework tries to place your last item somewhere in the ordered list the call looks similar to this:

```
(New MatrixCellData With {.SomeDouble = Nothing}).CompareTo(New MatrixCellData With {.SomeDouble = 25})
```

All the following checks are false:

```
If obj Is Nothing OrElse IsDBNull(obj) OrElse Not TypeOf (obj) Is MatrixCellData Then
```

Obj isn't Nothing, (Me.SomeDouble is Nothing)

This means your last line in the CompareTo method

```
Return Me.SomeDouble.Value.CompareTo(CType(obj, MatrixCellData).SomeDouble.Value)
```

In the case where Me.SomeDouble is Nothing, will actually be:

```
Return Nothing.Value.CompareTo(CType(obj, MatrixCellData).SomeDouble.Value)
```

Which of course doesn't make sense since Nothing does not have a 'Value' method or property.

I would re-write this as

```
Public Function CompareTo(obj As Object) As Integer Implements System.IComparable.CompareTo

    If obj Is Nothing OrElse Not TypeOf (obj) Is MatrixCellData OrElse CType(obj, MatrixCellData).SomeDouble Is Nothing Then
        Return 1
    Else If Me.SomeDouble is Nothing Then
        Return -1
    End If

    Return Me.SomeDouble.Value.CompareTo(CType(obj, MatrixCellData).SomeDouble.Value)
```

End Function

Comment: Okay thanks.  I think I follow.  What would recommend as an alternative so that NULLs are always pushed to last place?

Comment: @EvilDr I've edited my answer to show how i might tackle this. I did it in browser, hopefully it compiles with minimal changes :)

Comment: Works well.  Very helpful to have something to work from.  Thank you